# RegEx to Tokenize String

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to tokenize a string.  An example string would be.

```
John Mary, "Name=blah;Name=blahAgain" "Hand=1,2"
```

I'm trying to get back:

- John
- Mary
- Name=blah;Name=blahAgain
- Hand=1,2

Comment: One example (without any further explanation) might not be enough. Can there be `"` inside `"Name=blah;Name=blahAgain"`? Probably not, but it doesn't hurt to know. And what about spaces inside `"Name=blah;Name=blahAgain"`? Will the names always be two single names? What about `Jo Ellen Peter, ...` (`Jo Ellen` and `Peter`)? To name just a few of the possible problematic cases.

Answer (score 1):

For that specific example, I would do:

```
([^\s]*)\s+([^,\s]*)\s*,\s*"([^"]*)"\s+"([^"]*)"
```

**update**: modified to split Mary and John

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I'm using the Scanner class in java and it doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: That's strange. I'm quite sure that the above is fairly plain old-school regexp, without any weird PCRE or egrep stuff. Are you sure you've escaped the `"` with `\"` in java?

Comment: @Anthony: In the original question Mary and John was specified as a single token: they were not meant to be split. Obviously the spec have changed. Sigh.. never expected feature creep on SO

Comment: I'm fairly sure I have it in correctly.  Using the following string [Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([^,]*)\\s*,\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"\\s+\"([^\"]*)\"");]

Comment: Sorry, don't know java. Perhaps you should add java to your question tag to catch the eyes of java coders.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't catch John. You need another group in the beginning, like so: ([^ ]+) ([^,\s]*)\s*,\s*"([^"]*)"\s+"([^"]*)"

Answer (score 1):

This was easy:

```
([^ ])+
```

Comment: This would get the comma after Mary as well as the quotes. Also it wouldn't catch all desired fields at once.

Comment: Actually, it catches even only a single character each time, unless you put the '+' inside the parantheses.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Java, why not use StringTokenizer? E.g.:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("String to tokenize", " ");
while (st.hasMoreTokens())
{
   // get next token
   String someVariable = st.nextToken();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for your example:

```
(\w+) (\w+), \"([^"]+)" \"([^"]+)
```

Do all your string have exactly the same pattern?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way: split at `,` followed by a `space` or at one of `space` or `quotation mark`:

```
"John Mary, \"Name=blah;Name=blahAgain\" \"Hand=1,2\"".split(",\\s|[\\s\"]")
```